# How do I programatically change UITableViewCells text color at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to enable a "dark mode" feature to my app and in my tableview cells, I'm changing textcolors like so

```
    if ([FS isDarkModeEnabled]) {
        cell.CATEGORY.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.ORIGINUSER.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.NUMFILES.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.NUMTASKS.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.SHARECOUNT.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
```

I figured I'd replace the above code with a for loop but

```
for (id obj in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", ((UILabel *)obj).text);//<-- this spits out my storyboard placeholder text and not the acutal text for some reason.
        [((UILabel *)obj) setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
```

and

```
FSCategoriesTVCCell *cell2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
for (UILabel *lbl in [cell2.contentView subviews]) {
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

but am unable to get it working.

All the above code is done in `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

## edit to add some clarification

I know how to change the text colors manually, what I want to do is loop through the cell's content and change the colors via a for loop and NOT by declaring each label and changing each one individually.

Or, in shorter words, I want a `for` loop, not to do `cell.Label1.textColor = blah`

Comment: if you want to change the table cell text label color, you just need to do cell.textLabel.textColor in cellForRow method.

Comment: Are you using the default cell textLabel or do you have any labels declared in the cell ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri ive subclassed `UItableviewcell` to include 7 labels and an imageview

Answer (score 3):

When the dark mode is enabled by the user, you have to inform the tableview that it should update the cells. To do this, simply call tableView's `[tableView reloadData]` method.

Comment: i am using NSNotifications to handle that, please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:When View Load

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) 
  {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  cell.textLabel.text = @"highboi";
  return cell;
}
```

Option 2:When Click or Select the tableView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Did the OP state it wanted color change on selection?  Better to just set textColor of the labels in conditional logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and reload when the app's mode changes, as @Keneth suggests